# how can I setup a popup that shows different content based on my input in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am JavaScript beginner. 
Now I want to set up a click popup based on my input. 
My code is:

```
<div class="popup" onclick="myFunction()"> Equation
    <script scr="pop.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</div>
```

code for pop.js:

```
function myFunction(){
    var o=getValuesFromForm();
    var ans=o.Group;
    var smn="";
    if (ans=='a'){
        smn += '<span class="poptext" id="myPopup" style="front-size: 80%">I am in group A</span>';
    }
    else {
       smn += ' <span class="poptext" id="myPopup" style="front-size: 80%">I am in Group B</span>';
    }
    $('#myPopup').html(smn);
    $('#myPopup').classList.toggle("show");
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please read the tag(s) you included. You are asking an off-topic question. See [On Topic](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Your script needs to be above everything in the head, not inside the element thats being clicked.

Comment: jQuery exposes no `classList` property. Just call `.toggle()`.

Comment: Why @SpeedOfRound? Explain that because it is not really valid.

Comment: Looks like you are mixing jQuery and DOM. Error in the console should probably tell you that.

Comment: @epascarello aside from just being an excepted best practice, it lets you keep all of your script in one place so you don't have to go searching the page to find where you put things, and can also cause issues with the page loading before your script does, or effecting load time in general https://stackoverflow.com/a/24070373/5471957

Comment: There is a circular reference there: you create a `span` element with id `myPopup` and then you want that span HTML to be assigned to .... `myPopup`? What did you have in mind?

Comment: Oh yeah, @trincot is right, I assume you just mean to change the contents of an existing popup to the `poptext` span like you are doing, there's no need for the span to also have an id of `myPopup`.

Comment: Putting it in the head is not a best practice. Having it all in one place is not either. It is a personal opinion. Would be better at the end of the body, but has no impact of the problems with this code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some issues:

- jQuery does not expose a `classList` method. Just use the jQuery `.show()` method
- There is some circular reasoning: You create HTML that includes a `#myPopup` element, but then you select an element with that id from the current page and try to set its HTML to that. You should decide which is going to be `#myPopup`... It's a chicken-egg problem. I would suggest that you include in your original HTML the `#myPopup` element, and don't use that ID for the dynamically added `span` element.
- `front-size` should probably read `font-size`.

Here is how you can do it in a more jQuery style:

```js
// Stub for the function you did not include:
function getValuesFromForm() {
    return Object.fromEntries((new FormData(document.forms[0])).entries());
}

function myFunction(){
    var o = getValuesFromForm();
    var ans = o.Group;
    var smn = $('<span>').addClass("poptext").css("font-size", "80%")
                         .text("I am in group " + ans.toUpperCase());
    $('#myPopup').empty().append(smn).show();
}
```

```css
#myPopup {
    position: absolute;
    width: 300px;
    height: 50px;
    margin: 50px;
    border: 2px outset;
    display: none;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
    <select name="Group">
        <option>a</option>
        <option>b</option>
    </select>
</form>

<button class="popup" onclick="myFunction()">Equation</button>

<div id="myPopup"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It works.  I have another question: how to make the popup box disappeared if I click the button again, Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

```
function myFunction(){
var o={Group: 'a'};
var ans=o.Group;
var smn="";
if (ans=='a'){
  smn += '<span class="poptext" style="front-size: 80%">I am in group A</span>';
}
else {
 smn += ' <span class="poptext" style="front-size: 80%">I am in Group B</span>';
}

$('#myPopup').html(smn);
$('#myPopup').toggleClass("show");
}
```

As some people have mentioned, you needed to use `.toggleClass` because you are dealing with a jQuery object and not a DOM element.